# Input less than a second from start of game causes moved objects to move back to starting position

Tags: godot

I'm making a Puyo Puyo clone in Godot 4 and I'm hitting a bug at the start of the game.  The initial render looks like this, with the green puyo at coordinate (1,0) and the red one at (2,0):

[image]

The arrow keys move the puyos left, right and down, and their movement should be limited between the white borders.  If I wait roughly a second from when the game starts before pressing the left arrow key everything works as expected: the two puyos move to coordinate (0,0) at the top left.

If I don't wait and press the left arrow key immediately, the puyos move to (0,0), but then immediately bounce back to (1,0) or sometimes somewhere in between (0,0) and (1,0). The game now thinks the two puyos are at (0,0) and I can't move them any further left, but I can move them far enough to the right to put the red puyo out of bounds.

The game is structured like this at launch:

```
Root node
->Playfield
--->PuyoPair
----->Puyo1
----->Puyo2
```

playfield.gd controls the input and instantiates `PuyoPair` during its `_ready` function.  `PuyoPair` starts empty and then instantiates two puyos and randomly determines their color. The player's input moves `PuyoPair` which moves the puyos along with it.  `PuyoPair`'s position should always be at the top left of Puyo1, but when the error happens, `PuyoPair` is at (0,0) and the puyos are back at (1,0) and (2,0).

All scripts can be found [here](https://github.com/jcarvajal288/puyo-lab-godot/tree/main/scripts), and the game should be importable and runnable.

This feels like some kind of race condition, but I don't know enough about Godot to diagnose it. `playField`'s `_ready` function instantiates everything before any input happens, and I don't know what could be happening in that ~1 second after launch that would move the puyos.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason of your problem, but noticed that you are using RigidBody2D as base Node for your puyos. Their movement should be handled by Godot physics engine by applying forces. You should not use RigidBody2D for objects you move directly by setting their positions. Changing their type to CharacterBody2D fixes the problem for me. So maybe the problem is about physics system not being ready at the very start, or a conflict between physics system and position changes.

Comment: Changing to a CharacterBody2D indeed solves the problem.  I'll eventually want them to fall when I implement match clearing, but that's a problem for later.  If you write this comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason of your problem, but noticed that you are using RigidBody2D as base Node for your puyos. Their movement should be handled by Godot physics engine by applying forces. You should not use RigidBody2D for objects you move directly by setting their positions. Changing their type to CharacterBody2D fixes the problem for me. So maybe the problem is about physics system not being ready at the very start, or a conflict between physics system and position changes.